# Why am i getting this missing } after property list error? :(

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is something easy but I just can't see it. Can anyone tell me why I am getting the error "`missing } after property list`" for the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".single_image").live("click", function() {
    jwplayer().load({
        file: 'utubeurl'
    });
});​

</script>
```

the whole of the code is shown below:

```
            $(xml).find('item').each(function(i){
                var current=$(this);
                var ttl=current.find('title:first').text();
                var thum=current.find('thumbnail:first').text();
                var cat=current.find('category:first').text().split(',');
                var desc = current.find('description:first').text();
                var utubeurl = current.find('youtubeurl:first').text();
                var fbshareurl = current.find('facebookshareurl:first').text();
                var twturl = current.find('twitterurl:first').text();
                var nbcurl = current.find('nbcsiteurl:first').text();

                var item = {
                    title:ttl,
                    thumbnail:thum,
                    category:cat,
                    description:desc,
                    youtubeurl:utubeurl,
                    facebookshareurl:fbshareurl,
                    twitterurl:twturl,
                    nbcsiteurl:nbcurl,
                    obj:$('<div class="'+options.itemClass+'"><a id="'+parentId+'" class="single_image" title="'+desc+'"><script type="text/javascript"> $(".single_image").live("click",function(){ jwplayer().load({file:'+utubeurl+'}); }); </script><img src="'+thum+'" /></a><div class="show_lightbox_title"><strong>'+ttl+'</strong></div><ul id="social"><li><iframe src="'+fbshareurl+'" class="iframe_style" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"/></li><li><a class="twtbtn" href="'+twturl+'" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter_btn.gif"></a></li><a class="nbcbtn" href="'+nbcurl+'" target="_blank"><img src="images/showPages_btn.gif"></a></div>')
                };
                shows.push(item);
            });
```

Comment: I don't see anyting wrong. Is this right? http://jsfiddle.net/dsummersl/n9Vuk/

Comment: Is the "xml" tag on this question relevant?

Comment: If I copy your original code, I don't get any error... there is nothing wrong with what you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your property value, here:

```
obj:$('<div class="'+options.itemClass+'"><a id="'+parentId+'" class="single_image" title="'+desc+'"><script type="text/javascript"> $(".single_image").live("click",function(){ jwplayer().load({file:'+utubeurl+'}); }); </script><img src="'+thum+'" /></a><div class="show_lightbox_title"><strong>'+ttl+'</strong></div><ul id="social"><li><iframe src="'+fbshareurl+'" class="iframe_style" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"/></li><li><a class="twtbtn" href="'+twturl+'" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter_btn.gif"></a></li><a class="nbcbtn" href="'+nbcurl+'" target="_blank"><img src="images/showPages_btn.gif"></a></div>')
```

...this:

```
'... jwplayer().load({file:'+utubeurl+'}); ...'
```

...needs to be:

```
'... jwplayer().load({file:"'+utubeurl+'"}); ...'
```

...note the extra quotes.  Not sure if adding those quotes will break your looooooooong (difficult to read/support) string, you might need to escape them.  But you get the idea?

Cheers

Comment: it adds a container with unique content based on the xml info. Do you have an alternate route to creating the container with unique content without using so much code? How would you have done it?

Comment: Huh?  The reason you're getting the error is *you are missing required quotes around your property value* `utubeurl`. Look closely at the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the file property under quote marks , like so:

```
function () {

'file' : 'utubeurl'

}
```

--EDIT:

My bad , forget it , I was confusing with json, jquery and maybe some other j out there, you're definning a property , no need to make the name of the memory slot a string .

Comment: What Giovanni suggests is still valid, in fact all of your json keys should have quotes.  So put quotes around title, thumbnail, category, etc.

Comment: looks like that broke my code now it doesnt even work. so for example have this? var item = {
      'title':'ttl',
      'thumbnail':'thum',
      'category':'cat',
      'description':'desc',
      'youtubeurl':'utubeurl',
      'facebookshareurl':'fbshareurl',
      'twitterurl':'twturl',
      'nbcsiteurl':'nbcurl',

Comment: @DMoses: That would be true if it was JSON, but it's not. And even if it was, it would need to be double quotes, not single. So the suggestion is not valid.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity Thanks for the correction.  I knew the double-quote thing and just had a brain fart.  But I didn't understand that the ecma/js standards had different syntax for Object literals than the JSON standard.  You made me go look it up and find the BNF for object literals. :)

Answer (score 1):

When I copy and paste that block of code, I see an extra character trailing the second closing });

Removing that executes fine in console for me, so if that is not the source of the error I would look elsewhere on the page.

Is the page publicly accessible?

Comment: The [original revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10526414/1) does not seem to have that problem though...

Comment: Is the page where this code is failing publicly viewable. Can I see the page where the error is occurring. I don't get an error here.

Comment: Ah... don't ask me, ask the OP ;)

Comment: Madbreaks got it, the snippet didn't provide enough context. He's right, the url is being dumped without surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by passing a variable through href and then passing it into the command to play the url.

```
var item = {
                    title:ttl,
                    thumbnail:thum,
                    category:cat,
                    description:desc,
                    youtubeurl:utubeurl,
                    facebookshareurl:fbshareurl,
                    twitterurl:twturl,
                    nbcsiteurl:nbcurl,
                    obj:$('<div class="'+options.itemClass+'"><a href="javascript:utubeurlParser(\''+utubeurl+'\')" id="'+parentId+'" class="single_image" title="'+desc+'"><img src="'+thum+'" /></a><div class="show_lightbox_title"><strong>'+ttl+'</strong></div><ul id="social"><li><iframe src="'+fbshareurl+'" class="iframe_style" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"/></li><li><a class="twtbtn" href="'+twturl+'" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter_btn.gif"></a></li><a class="nbcbtn" href="'+nbcurl+'" target="_blank"><img src="images/showPages_btn.gif"></a></div>')
                };
                shows.push(item);
            });

            setSetter();
        }
    });
}
utubeurlParser = function(url){
              jwplayer().load({file: [url]});}
```